# How to Add Custom posts inside Trending Now section of Magazine Base Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am new to WordPress, so it might be silly questions to you people. I am using **Magazine Base free theme** provided by wordpress community.

I am adding post with featured image in it, sometimes it gets added to Trending now section, sometimes not. So can anyone please advise me, How to add custom posts on Trending Now section.

Comment: To add custom post type you can add plugin or custom code. There are many plugins you can find like "Custom Post Type UI" and "Custom Post Type Maker".

Comment: Thanks Ranjit, but I especially talking about Trending Now section of Magazine Base theme, I have observed that, there were some particular categories, if those are selected then that post shown on Trending Now, but if we unchecked anyone of those categories, then post was not shown on the section anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I got the resolution, Thanks Anyways. Its becuase of theme customization setting, which take only Lifestyle as a category for Trending Now section.

Anyways Thanks a lot !!